# Why do I get two AppV tray icons after adding a package as an admin?

Tags: powershell, appv

If I log in to a Windows machine as a regular user, I get an AppV system tray icon and a process, AppVStreamingUX.exe, to match. That's all fine. When I want to add a package to my client, I need to open Powershell as administrator, that's fine too. However, after invoking the "Add-AppVClientPackage" command, I now have two system tray icons and, of course, two AppVStreamingUX.exe processes -- one for me and one for admin. Even after exiting Powershell, the second one remains, and now I have two system tray icons, and that's just confusing.

So, how can I use Powershell as an admin to add a package, without starting a second AppVStreamingUX.exe process?

Answer (score 0):

This was fundamental to the SP1 behaviour of App-V 5.  The service would launch the .EXE in the users (your elevated) context.
They 'fixed' it with SP2 and above by removing the GUI entirely...

You could exit the process interactively from the System tray, or terminate the process if it's username matches $env:username?

Something like:

```
$a = gwmi -Class win32_process -Filter 'name="notepad.exe"'
foreach ($i in $a) {
    $u = $i.GetOwner()
    If ($u.User -EQ $env:USERNAME) {Write-Host matched! $i.ProcessId}
}
```